# MailKit authentication fails

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc, mailkit

I have the code below

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage();

        MailboxAddress from = new MailboxAddress("Admin",
        "myemail@gmail.com");
        message.From.Add(from);

        MailboxAddress to = new MailboxAddress("User",
        "myemail2@gmail.com");
        message.To.Add(to);

        message.Subject = "Hi user";
        BodyBuilder bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder();
        bodyBuilder.TextBody = "message body here";
        message.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        
        client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
        client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 465, true);
        client.Authenticate("myemail@gmail.com", "pass");
        client.Send(message);
        client.Disconnect(true);
        client.Dispose();
```

It says my credentials are not correct even though they are. I'm using `MailKit` and `MimeMessage`.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like that.

```
var message = new MimeMessage();
message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Test Project",
"your email"));
message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("pritom", email));
message.Subject = "Hi,this is demo email";
message.Body = new TextPart("plain")
{
Text = "Hello,My First Demo Mail it is.Thanks",
};
//add attach
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
BodyBuilder bb = new BodyBuilder();
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
//bb.Attachments.Add("attachmentName",
wc.DownloadData("wwwroot/Images/H.pdf"));
bb.Attachments.Add("Email.pdf",
wc.DownloadData("wwwroot/Images/Email.pdf"));
//bb.Attachments.Add("H.pdf", new MemoryStream());
}
message.Body = bb.ToMessageBody();
//end attach
using (var client = new SmtpClient())
{
client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, false);
client.Authenticate("your email",
"yourpassword");
client.Send(message);
client.Disconnect(true);
}
```

**Update**

go to this link

[enter link description here](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)

and allow a less secure app.

Comment: thats what im doing but the authentication fails for some reason

Comment: https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps  go to this link and enable this action.

Comment: @PritomSarkar without allowing a less secure app how can we authenticate users using OAuth2.0?

Comment: @PrashantGirase https://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/sdk/html/object_oauth.htm

Answer (score 1):

try to use port 587 instead of 465.
Here's the link to my github repository, a simple project to send mails.
https://github.com/osman-developer/sendingMails

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing the same issue, go on your gmail account > security > allow less secure apps. This solved my problem